# Edit Source location in Robot framework log.html

Tags: robotframework

I need to be able to edit Source in Robot framework log to a repository link.

Attached snapshot for reference. 
[image]

I tried setting the `${SUITE_SOURCE}` and expected that would reflect in the log. Apparently not.

Is there any way I could do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it may not be directly apparent to others, this is the value the poster is referring to. It is the Source reference in the Robot Framework log file.

[image]

As you've noticed the `${SUITE_SOURCE}` variable does not update this value. It is also expected as this value should be considered a constant value so that you always can use it in your keywords.

However, as the log files are based on the `output.xml` you can update the relevant values in the xml and the rerun the log and report creation using the `rebot output.xml` command. This is a command that is part of the standard Robot Framework installation.